# Package architecture (AMD64) does not match system (i386) on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, java, dpkg

I have Ubuntu:

```
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
```

This is output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 15
model       : 47
model name  : AMD Athlon(tm) 64 Processor 3400+
stepping    : 2
cpu MHz     : 1000.000
cache size  : 512 KB
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 1
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt lm 3dnowext 3dnow up extd_apicid pni lahf_lm
bogomips    : 2000.17
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts fid vid ttp tm stc
```

This is output of `dpkg --version`:

```
Debian `dpkg' package management program version 1.16.1.2 (i386).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
```

Despite dpkg is compiled for i386, it seems I have Amd64 as a processor. But when I install Java:

```
sudo dpkg -i sun-java6-bin_6-06-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

I have this error:

```
dpkg: error processing sun-java6-bin_6-06-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sun-java6-bin_6-06-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you are trying to install a 64-bit deb on a 32-bit operating system which is not possible.

[Download the appropriate 32-bit deb file](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/i386/sun-java6-bin/download) and then try to install it. Also note that the linked deb file was packaged for Hardy (8.04) and can very well open you up for security threats given how outdated the package is and the withdrawal of any future security updates for Sun Java from Oracle.

Comment: But I have: "model name  : AMD Athlon(tm) 64 Processor 3400+" in /proc/cpuinfo ...

Comment: What matters is not what your computer can do but what architecture you have installed. What did you get for `uname -m`?